# Core Data y fetch con predicate variable

Tags: ios, swift3

Hago una solicitud a una de las entidades de ***Core Data***, pero para hacer un cálculo, tengo que filtrar los resultados por los que cumplen dos condiciones:

- Que uno de sus atributos (bool), sea `true`.
- Que otro de sus atributos (date), se encuentre entre el día 16 del mes anterior y el día 15 del mes en curso.

Ejemplo:

```
func setDiasTMAnt() -> Int{
    if let context = context{
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Gastos> = Gastos.fetchRequest()
        let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dayTM == true")
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortByDate]
        request.predicate = predicate
        do{
            let fetchedDayTM = try context.fetch(request)
            self.diasTM = fetchedDayTM
        }catch{
            print("Error al definir los días de TM en el mes anterior")
        }
        return diasTM.count
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

Quiero que se cumplan las dos condiciones al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Crea los dos predicados:

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate)

let booleanPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dayTM == true")
```

Y añádelos en un NSCompoundPredicate:

```
let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type:NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates:[datePredicate, booleanPredicate])
```

Finalmente añade el NSCompoundPredicate como predicate:

```
request.predicate = andPredicate
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Comment: Lo probaré y cuento que tal fue!! gracias!

Comment: ¿Has podido hacer la prueba?

Comment: Si, no ha funcionado. Pero por motivos personales no pude continuar con el proyecto. Lo siento por no dar novedades.